# Spark3 Vector UDF vs Regular UDF

Tags: scala, pyspark, user-defined-functions, scalatest, spark3

What is the difference between udf and vector udf in spark 3 as vectorized udf is new feature as per spark documentation

I know in In Spark 3, a user-defined function (UDF) is a function that you can define in a programming language such as Python or Scala and apply to data in Spark DataFrame or Dataset. A UDF takes one or more columns as input and produces a new column as output.

Answer (score 1):

I experimented with simple unit test case and found that udf is simple on one element
but vector udf operates on Array or struct

A vectorized UDF is a new feature in Spark 3 that is designed to improve the performance of UDFs by allowing them to process multiple rows at once, instead of processing one row at a time.

A vectorized UDF takes one or more columns as input and produces a new column as output, just like a regular UDF. However, instead of processing each row individually, a vectorized UDF operates on a batch of rows at once, which can result in significant performance improvements.

**Note :**
not all UDFs can be vectorized. Only UDFs that operate on arrays or structs can be vectorized in Spark 3+

below is the full example :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SparkSession}
import org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll
import org.scalatest.funsuite.AnyFunSuite
import org.scalatest.matchers.should.Matchers

/**
 * note that not all UDFs can be vectorized. Only UDFs that operate on arrays or structs can be vectorized in Spark 3+.
 */
class VectorizedUDFsSpec extends AnyFunSuite with Matchers with BeforeAndAfterAll {
  private var spark: SparkSession = _

  override def beforeAll(): Unit = {
    spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .appName("VectorizedUDFsSpec")
      .master("local[*]")
      .getOrCreate()
  }

  override def afterAll(): Unit = {
    spark.stop()
  }

  test("addOne UDF should add one to a number") {
    val spark1 = spark
    import spark1.implicits._
    val addOne = udf((x: Int) => x + 1)

    val df: DataFrame = Seq((1), (2), (3)).toDF("num")
    val dfWithAddOne = df.withColumn("num_plus_one", addOne($"num"))

    val result = dfWithAddOne.collect()

    assert(result.length === 3)
    assert(result(0).getAs[Int]("num_plus_one") === 2)
    assert(result(1).getAs[Int]("num_plus_one") === 3)
    assert(result(2).getAs[Int]("num_plus_one") === 4)
  }

  test("addOneVectorized UDF should add one to a column of numbers") {
    val spark1 = spark
    import spark1.implicits._
    val addOneVectorized = udf((xs: Seq[Int]) => xs.map(_ + 1))

    val df: DataFrame = Seq((Array(1,2,3)), (Array(2)), (Array(3))).toDF("num")
    val dfWithAddOneVectorized = df.withColumn("num_plus_one", addOneVectorized($"num"))
    dfWithAddOneVectorized.show(false)
    val result = dfWithAddOneVectorized.collect()

    assert(result.length === 3)
    assert(result(0).getAs[Seq[Int]]("num_plus_one") === Seq(2,3,4))
    assert(result(1).getAs[Seq[Int]]("num_plus_one") === Seq(3))
    assert(result(2).getAs[Seq[Int]]("num_plus_one") === Seq(4))
  }
}
```

output :
**regular udf**

```
+---+------------+
|num|num_plus_one|
+---+------------+
|1  |2           |
|2  |3           |
|3  |4           |
+---+------------+
```

**vectorized udf :**

```
+---------+------------+
|num      |num_plus_one|
+---------+------------+
|[1, 2, 3]|[2, 3, 4]   |
|[2]      |[3]         |
|[3]      |[4]         |
+---------+------------+
```

***Conclusion :***

The key difference between a UDF and a vectorized UDF in Spark 3 is that the latter is a new feature designed to improve the performance of UDFs by processing batches of rows at once instead of processing each row individually.